# Latitude E7250 second SSD

Tags: m.2

I have a Latitude E7250.  I want to add a second SSD.  Has anyone attempted or had any success with this? There is an m.2 connector that is labeled WWAN HCA.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, it looks like this question was asked elsewhere. Please check out this question/answer and let us know if your question is different:  http://superuser.com/questions/907961/dell-latitude-e5550-m-2-slots-what-can-i-use

Comment: Here's another Q/A that goes into the same subject: http://superuser.com/questions/743040/will-a-sata-ssd-drive-work-in-wwan-minipcie-slot

Answer (score 1):

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19651895

Dell will likely tell you this slot will only accept a Wireless/network card.

The m.2 connector are PCIe connectors, not mSATA, and the m.2 drives use the PCIe interface, so it is possible they'll work, but BIOS updates could break this function, and there will probably not be official support of any kind.

In other words: proceed at your own risk, but you could get lucky.